# R version 3.0.2 cannot find RCurl package

Tags: r, rcurl, rcharts

I'm using R version 3.0.2 on my Windows 7 (32-bit) system and am stumped trying to install rCharts. I've had no problem installing other packages from github (e.g., slidify), but R seems unable to find the dependent RCurl package I installed.

I can submit the following basic lines of code without error:

```
require(devtools) 
library(bitops,lib.loc='c:/R/packages/')
library(RCurl,lib.loc='c:/R/packages/')
require(RCurl)    # have also tried the library function without luck*
```

But, when I submit the command to install rCharts with

```
install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv')
```

I get the following :

```
Installing github repo(s) rCharts/master from ramnathv
Downloading rCharts.zip from https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/archive/master.zip
Installing package from C:\Users\nakamura\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwzYzaG/rCharts.zip
Installing rCharts
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/i386/R" --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:\Users\nakamura\AppData\Local\temp\RtmpwzYzaG\rCharts-master"  \
  --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library" --with-keep.source  \
  --install-tests 

**ERROR: dependency 'RCurl' is not available for package 'rCharts'**
*** removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/rCharts'
Error: Command failed (1)**
```

I've tried installing libcurl, but am not sure I've unzipped it to the correct folder. (From what I've been able to gather from bits and pieces of other questions about rCurl, it seems having an improper/no installation of libcurl could be a contributing factor?)

Any help would be very much appreciated. I feel like I'm going around in circles.

Ann

Comment: I think Windows 7 & 8 have separate library folders for 32 and 64 bit versions of R. You might check to see whether the 32 bit version of rCurl (if there is such a thing) is installed in the correct location. There is sometimes the need for installing RTools for source installs which many packages in archive status are.

Comment: On Windows 7, at least, all packages are in one library folder, so I suspect it's not that. It looks like perhaps you're saving packages in a non-standard location. What does `find.package("RCurl")` give you?

Comment: Thanks for responding, DWin and Thomas. I do suspect this problem has something to do with where I'm keeping my packages. I've been keeping them all in one folder (c:/R/packages). find.package("RCurl") gives me:  "c:/R/packages/RCurl"

Comment: I thought I'd comment for others with this problem. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction.  I added the directory "C:/R/packages" to the front of the .libPaths variable to help R find RCurl. After submitting the command, .libPaths( "c:/R/packages"), I was successful. Thanks, again!

Comment: You might want to post your resolution as an answer and accept it so that this question can be marked complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the directory "C:/R/packages" to the front of the .libPaths variable will help R find RCurl if it's been installed to a non-standard directory.